# Python: Multiple While Loops inside a While Loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, nested

'''Hello, I'm trying to figure out why my second while loop, within a while loop is not executing in Python.'''

```
x = True
y = False
z = True

    while x == True

        while y == True
            print("Won't print")

        while z == True
            print("Should print, right?")
```

Comment: You need to fix the indentation and put a colon at the end of each while line, then it will work

Comment: careful, this may freeze your GUI...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, doing `while x == True` is redundant, you can just do `while x`, and second you are missing the colon at the end of the while statements. Also you must respect the indentation in python. Try this:

```
x = True
y = False
z = True

while x:
    while y:
        print("Won't print")

    while z:
        print("Should print, right?")
```